# Displaying geom_smooth() trend line from a specified x value

Tags: r, ggplot2

Suppose a dataset containing count data per multiple time periods and per multiple groups in the following format:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(group = as.factor(rep(1:3, each = 50)),
                 week = rep(1:50, 3),
                 rate = c(round(700 - rnorm(50, 100, 10) - 1:50 * 2, 0),
                          round(1000 - rnorm(50, 200, 10) - 1:50 * 2, 0),
                          round(1000 - rnorm(50, 200, 10) - 1:50 * 2, 0)))

    group week rate
1       1    1  604
2       1    2  598
3       1    3  578
4       1    4  591
5       1    5  589
6       1    6  571
7       1    7  581
8       1    8  597
9       1    9  589
10      1   10  584
```

I'm interested in fitting a model-based trend line per groups, however, I want this trend line to be displayed only from a certain x value. To visualize the trend line using all data points (requires `ggplot2`):

```
df %>%
 ggplot(aes(x = week,
            y = rate,
            group = group,
            lty = group)) + 
 geom_line() +
 geom_point() +
 geom_smooth(method = "glm", 
             method.args = list(family = "quasipoisson"),
             se = FALSE)
```

[image: Plot 1]

Or to fit a model based on a specific range of values (requires `ggplot2` and `dplyr`):

```
df %>%
 group_by(group) %>%
 mutate(rate2 = ifelse(week < 35, NA, rate)) %>%
 ggplot(aes(x = week,
            y = rate,
            group = group,
            lty = group)) + 
 geom_line() +
 geom_point() +
 geom_smooth(aes(y = rate2),
             method = "glm", 
             method.args = list(family = "quasipoisson"),
             se = FALSE)
```

[image: Plot 2]

However, I cannot find a way to fit the models using all data, but display the trend line only from a specific x value (let's say 35+). Thus, I essentially want the trend line as computed for plot one, but displaying it according the second plot, using `ggplot2` and ideally only one pipeline.

Comment: Pass `xseq` : `geom_smooth(method = "glm",       method.args = list(family = "quasipoisson"), xseq=seq(35,50,by=1),   se = FALSE)`

Comment: @user20650 This is very close to what I'm looking for. The only caveat is that it requires to specify the upper limit. I would like to specify only the lower limit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I went to look at the `after_stat` function mentioned by @tjebo. See if the following works for you?

```
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = week,
             y = rate,
             lty = group)) + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "glm", 
              aes(group = after_stat(interaction(group, x > 35)),
                  colour = after_scale(alpha(colour, as.numeric(x > 35)))),
              method.args = list(family = "quasipoisson"),
              se = F)
```

[image: result]

This works by splitting the points associated with each line into two groups, those in the x <=35 region and those in the x >35 region, since a line's colour shouldn't vary, and defining a separate colour transparency for each new group. As a result, only the lines in the x > 35 region are visible.

When used, the code triggers a warning that the `after_scale` modification isn't applied to the legend. I don't think that's a problem though, since we don't need it to appear in the legend anyway.

Answer (score 6):

If you can tolerate a warning, you can solve this with 1 line difference from the example code using `stage()`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(group = as.factor(rep(1:3, each = 50)),
                 week = rep(1:50, 3),
                 rate = c(round(700 - rnorm(50, 100, 10) - 1:50 * 2, 0),
                          round(1000 - rnorm(50, 200, 10) - 1:50 * 2, 0),
                          round(1000 - rnorm(50, 200, 10) - 1:50 * 2, 0)))

df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = week,
             y = rate,
             group = group,
             lty = group)) + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "glm", 
              method.args = list(family = "quasipoisson"),
              aes(x = stage(week, after_stat = ifelse(x > 35, x, NA))),
              se = FALSE) 
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'
#> Warning: Removed 165 rows containing missing values (geom_smooth).
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

One way to do this is to construct the fitted values outside of `ggplot` so you have control over them:

```
df$fit <- glm(rate ~ week + group, data = df, family = "quasipoisson")$fitted.values

library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = week, group = group, lty = group)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = rate)) +
  geom_point(aes(y = rate)) +
  geom_line(data = df %>% filter(week >= 35), aes(y = fit), color = "blue", size = 1.25)
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's quite reasonable, however, it would be nice to see a solution that does not  require this additional step.

Answer (score 4):

1. I am not sure if it is *generally* correct to use a linear model in time series. The whole point about time series is that they require specific statistics because of their expected **autocorrelation**. You might want something like average rolling models instead.
2. I am not sure if your visualisation might not be quite confusing and, more dangerously, misleading.

Besides, an interesting problem. I thought the new `after_stat` might somehow help, but I couldn't get it working.

So, here a quick hack. Change the order of your geom-s and draw a rectangle in-between. I am cheekily using a different theme, but if you really want to use `theme_grey()`, you can fake the axis lines as well.

```r
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(group = as.factor(rep(1:3, each = 50)),
                 week = rep(1:50, 3),
                 rate = c(round(700 - rnorm(50, 100, 10) - 1:50 * 2, 0),
                          round(1000 - rnorm(50, 200, 10) - 1:50 * 2, 0),
                          round(1000 - rnorm(50, 200, 10) - 1:50 * 2, 0)))
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = week, y = rate, group = group, lty = group)) + 
  stat_smooth(se = FALSE) +
  geom_rect(xmin = -Inf, xmax = 35, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, 
            fill = "white") +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  theme_classic()
#> `geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-02-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

P.S. I've removed a few of the unnecessary bits in the code to reproduce this, like the model specs.

Comment: Thank you for your cautionary remarks, however, I'm aware of it. Here, I just wanted for the sake of fun replicate and slightly extend this plot: https://twitter.com/d_spiegel/status/1358397800799682560 Also thank you for the solution! I've though that it might be solved in a similar fashion, but was unable to come up with the right solution.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `ggplot_build` to get the structure of the plot :

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = week,
                        y = rate,
                        group = group,
                        lty = group)) + 
                  geom_line() +
                  geom_point() +
                  geom_smooth(method = "glm", 
                              method.args = list(family = "quasipoisson"),
                              se = FALSE) 
p_build <- ggplot_build(p)
```

[image]

You could then modify the internal data, here the third element of the data list (`geom_smooth`):

```
p_build$data[[3]]$x <- sapply(p_build$data[[3]]$x,function(x) {ifelse(x<35,NA,x)})
```

and use `ggplot_gtable` to regenerate the plot (the `lm` calculations still apply to the whole dataset):

```
plot(ggplot_gtable(p_build))
```

[image]

Comment: @tmfmnk, forgot to set seed to 123 to get the same results : corrected